# How to change the default input method in the input area of dash,folder rename, etc

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, input-method

I'm using a Chinese input method(fcitx4.1).

when I starting input in dash(or rename in folder), 
the words didn't came out.
I had to right click in the input area and 
change the input method from "System(X input method)" to "none" or something.

As it's now impossible to input chinese character in them, 
Is there any method that could change the default input method in the input area to "none" or others ?

Answer (score 2):

Install Input Method Switcher from Software Center and select ibus as the default method for your locale. I also had the same problem with the Greek language and this solved it.

Or from terminal use the command "im-switch -s ibus", after installing of course the package "im-switch"

Comment: emm, in fact, I have the im-switch installed.(input chinese always need that.)
but the problem now is if I use fcitx,I'm unable typeing words in the 
dash. but it's OK with ibus or other input methods.
So I thought it's a bug of the fcitx input method.
And still thanks for your answer.